# Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript

I created a function for setting multiple `HTML` attributes at once -

```js
function attrs(element: HTMLElement, attrs: { [key: string]: string | number }): void {
  for (let attr in attrs) {
    element.setAttribute(attr, typeof attrs[attr] === 'number' ? attrs[attr].toString() : attrs[attr])
  }
}
```

I was trying to generic object which accepts **key** of type `string` and **value** of type `string` or `number`. But as we know `setAttribute()` takes **2 args** of type `string`. I put a check; to check whether the **value** is type of `string` or `number` and if the type is `number` I changed it to string as you can see in the function.

Even then I am getting

```
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

**P.S** - Also suggest a better title for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an intermediate variable to help with the narrowing:

```
function attrs(element: HTMLElement, attrs: { [key: string]: string | number }): void {
  for (let attr in attrs) {
    const attrValue = attrs[attr];
    element.setAttribute(attr, typeof attrValue === 'number' ? attrValue.toString() : attrValue)
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQylATgZwBQFMA2uAtrmFAFyIASAKgLIAyAooSWQDQppaUDeiAbQDWuAJ6VMGGGADmAXQlTZiAD6IwIIgCNc6RAF8AlJQBucGABNEvAFCJEwOHuyEoXDImnush63fuIEAiS3gBqyPgguIgAvN6YAqgYcgDc-vYExKRQAHSYuFAAgtwwWiBQuNhJ6JxQogAOuHDAYRFRsTFxAOQa2rpdiAD8rZG4OVBwAMpKMti%20lNXho4b%20%20jZrQA)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Can you also tell why it is not working without the intermediate variable??

Comment: @KunalTanwar  There is an open bug about this if you're interested on this topic : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530